# How to configure highlighting in Emacs diff mode?

Tags: version-control, emacs, diff, syntax-highlighting

I use `mercurial.el` mode with Emacs. When I run `vc-diff`, I can see the diff, but, unlike the source code, it is not nicely highlighted:

[image: Emacs vc-diff]

Reading such diffs is difficult. How do I configure Emacs,

1. to highlight `-` and `+` lines with different colors? (red and blue, for example)
2. to highlight word difference (like BitBucket and GitHub do)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using <kbd>M-x ediff-revision</kbd>, which does an [`ediff`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ediff/index.html) instead of just a regular diff.  That will give you word-differences and a side-by-side (or top/bottom) display.  Check out the [ediff manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ediff/index.html).

The Emacs wiki also has a number of modes for just regular diff files (like what you're looking at) - [check it out](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiffMode).

To just change the colors in the `diff-mode` which you're currently using, you can do something like:

```
(defun update-diff-colors ()
  "update the colors for diff faces"
  (set-face-attribute 'diff-added nil
                      :foreground "white" :background "blue")
  (set-face-attribute 'diff-removed nil
                      :foreground "white" :background "red3")
  (set-face-attribute 'diff-changed nil
                      :foreground "white" :background "purple"))
(eval-after-load "diff-mode"
  '(update-diff-colors))
```

Comment: I check **"DarkGreen"** and **"DarkRed"** colors for added/removed under terminal and in 4-/8-bit (16/256 colors) terminal both look very nice!

Comment: Thanks for the cut n' pasteable example as well as the link to docs.